# Parsing csv file with unknown delimiter symbol

Tags: .net, parsing, csv, delimiter

I have to write (or use existing) csv parsing library.

The problem is that files are uploaded in different formats with different delimiter symbols for example:

```
File1:
field1; field2; field3; field4
field1; field2; field3; field4

File2:
feld1, field2, field3, field4
feld1, field2, field3, field4

File3:
"field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"
"field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"
```

What is the best way to programmaticaly understand which symbol is actual delimiter for columns?

I'm thinking about writing my own method with symbols statistical analysis, but maybe there are existing solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use regexes (hoping not to get as many downvotes as the last time ;) ). I'm taking advantage of [backreferences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx) which allows basically to use previously captured groups. You can also have different separators in the same file as long as every line uses the same separator (don't know if it is useful though).

So, this is how I build the regex:

```
string csvItem = @"[""']?\w+[""']?";
string separator = @"\s*[,\.;-]\s*";
string pattern = string.Format(@"^({0}(?<sep>{1}){0})+(\k<sep>{0})*$",
    csvItem, separator);
```

csvItem is an item (column) in the csv. It can contain lowercase or uppercase letters, digits and the underscore and can be optionally surrounded with " or '.

separator separates items. It is composed by one of these characters ,.;- and zero or more spacing characters.

The pattern says that a valid line is composed at least two csvItems separated by the separator. Note the backreference -> \k

Here it is. This is the content of the test file:

```
field1; field2; field3; field4
field1; field2; field3; field4

feld1, field2, field3, field4
feld1, field2, field3, field4

"field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"
"field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"
```

And a sample console project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace csvParser {
    class Program {
        static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines( @"e:\prova.csv" );

            for ( int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++ ) {
                string csvItem = @"[""']?\w+[""']?";
                string separator = @"\s*[,\.;-]\s*";
                string pattern = string.Format(@"^({0}(?<sep>{1}){0})+(\k<sep>{0})*$", csvItem, separator);

                var rex = new Regex( pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline );
                var match = rex.Match( lines[ i ] );

                if ( match == null ) {
                    Console.WriteLine( "No match on line {0}", i );
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    string sep = match.Groups[ "sep" ].Value;

                    Console.WriteLine( "--- Line #{0} ---------------", i );
                    Console.WriteLine( "Line is '{0}'", lines[ i ] );
                    Console.WriteLine( "Separator is '{0}'", sep );

                    Console.WriteLine( "Items are:" );
                    foreach ( string item in lines[ i ].Split( sep ) )
                        Console.WriteLine( "\t'{0}'", item );

                    Console.WriteLine( );
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey( );
        }
    }

    public static partial class Extension {
        public static string[ ] Split( this string str, string sep ) {
            return str.Split( new string[ ] { sep }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
        }
    }
}
```

Finally its output:

```
--- Line #0 ---------------
Line is 'field1; field2; field3; field4'
Separator is '; '
Items are:
        'field1'
        'field2'
        'field3'
        'field4'

--- Line #1 ---------------
Line is 'field1; field2; field3; field4'
Separator is '; '
Items are:
        'field1'
        'field2'
        'field3'
        'field4'

--- Line #2 ---------------
Line is ''
Separator is ''
Items are:

--- Line #3 ---------------
Line is 'feld1, field2, field3, field4'
Separator is ', '
Items are:
        'feld1'
        'field2'
        'field3'
        'field4'

--- Line #4 ---------------
Line is 'feld1, field2, field3, field4'
Separator is ', '
Items are:
        'feld1'
        'field2'
        'field3'
        'field4'

--- Line #5 ---------------
Line is ''
Separator is ''
Items are:

--- Line #6 ---------------
Line is '"field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"'
Separator is ', '
Items are:
        '"field1"'
        '"field2"'
        '"field3"'
        '"field4"'

--- Line #7 ---------------
Line is '"field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"'
Separator is ', '
Items are:
        '"field1"'
        '"field2"'
        '"field3"'
        '"field4"'
```

Unfortunately the regex captures empty lines, too. Trying to fix it :)

Comment: Thanks, it's f*cking awesome approach!

Comment: However your approach needs the predefined list of possible delimiters.. I'd like to have a method that will calcaulte most possible delimiters for a given file.

Comment: @Ruslan: well, I think that's quite difficult to do. You should at least know what kind of separator you are looking for or what characters they contain.

Comment: doesn' work when csv is formated with double quates and space.